# Texture slot not getting picked properly in shader issue

Tags: opengl, glsl

For the cube object here, texture id is 1.0f for all the vertices. 
And the texture bound to GL_TEXTURE1. 
The Box renders as follows: 
[image: Texture slot loading]

To check if i was passing the correct texture id, have enabled this code in below shader which gave the following result

```
    //Checking texture id with index
    //texColor = vec4(float(index),float(index),float(index),float(index));
```

[image: Texture slot int value]

To check the float value of the texture id I was passing , enabled below code and saw following

```
    //Checking texture id with float index
    //texColor = vec4(v_TexIndex,v_TexIndex,v_TexIndex,v_TexIndex);
```

[image: Texture slot float value]

It seems like the float to int conversion here is messing up.

```
highp int index = int(v_TexIndex);
```

So to fix this i did below and got the correct result.

```
highp int index = int(v_TexIndex+0.1);
```

[image]

It looks like for some vertices v_TexIndex is 0.99 and adding 0.1 helps it round of to 1 when int conversion happens.

So, i was wondering why is v_TexIndex value not proper when it comes to the fragment shader?

```
#shader vertex
#version 440 core

layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec4 color;
layout(location = 2) in vec2 texCoords;
layout(location = 3) in float texIndex;

out vec2 v_TexCoord;
out vec4 v_Color;
out float v_TexIndex;

uniform mat4 u_MVP;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = u_MVP*position;
    v_TexCoord = texCoords;
    v_Color = color;
    v_TexIndex = texIndex;
}

#shader fragment
#version 440 core

layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;

in vec2 v_TexCoord;
in vec4 v_Color;
in float v_TexIndex;

uniform sampler2D u_Textures[32];
uniform float u_SelectColorf;

void main()
{

    highp int index = int(v_TexIndex);

    vec4 SelectColorVec = vec4(u_SelectColorf,u_SelectColorf,u_SelectColorf,u_SelectColorf);
    vec4 OneMinusSelectColorVec = vec4(1.0f-u_SelectColorf,1.0f-u_SelectColorf,1.0f-u_SelectColorf,1.0f-u_SelectColorf);

    vec4 texColor = OneMinusSelectColorVec * texture(u_Textures[index],v_TexCoord);
    texColor += SelectColorVec * v_Color;

    //Checking texture id with index
    //texColor = vec4(float(index),float(index),float(index),float(index));

    //Checking texture id with float index
    //texColor = vec4(v_TexIndex,v_TexIndex,v_TexIndex,v_TexIndex);

    color = texColor;
}
```

Comment: Values passed from Vertex to Fragment Shader are inevitable interpolated. Floating point math is unstable, so that even if all 3 vertices have the same value, the calculations are still applied leading to rounding issues. You may try **flat** qualifier for passing variable, but I don't think it will help. So that converting float to integer with +0.1 is one of proper and simpler ways to do that. There is also **ceil()** function for your case, but it would be a waste.

Comment: Found a cleaner way of doing it : highp int index = int(round(v_TexIndex));

Comment: If your index is never negative, your `round` variant is just a more complicated version of `int(value+0.5)`. But the bigger issue I see here is `uniform sampler2D u_Textures[32]`. Don't do this. FIrst of all, the GL spec (even the latest 4.6 one) only guarantees 16 texture units per shader stage, use array textures instead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue happens due to interpolation errors. 
The important point to note is each of the v_TexIndex defined per vertex in a triangle. 
So when it goes to fragment shader the in-between points v_TexIndex need to be interpolated and interpolation errors can happen.

2 Reasonable fixes: 
i. If TexIndex is comming from VBO, do the following in fragment shader.

```
int index = int(v_TexIndex+0.5);
```

ii. Define a uniform int u_TexIndex and set it before draw call.